# Take off immediately/ right away / in a hurry

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I know 'take off' means 'to leave a place suddenly.' I was talking about the 'US / Afghanistan issue' with someone online. (Just so you know it was just a casual conversation, neither of us was an expert on the topic.)

I said "I wonder why the US soldiers **took off** in a hurry like they did."

Is it natural to add words like 'hurry/ immediately/ right away etc.' after 'take off' since it already means 'to leave a place suddenly'?

Comment: Yes it is natural. Is there some reason you're asking? It might help us to give you a more satisfying answer if we knew.

Answer (score 1):

It is natural and it actually helps the sentence.

1. They **took off**
2. They **took off in a hurry**

In 1., maybe they **took off** but were supposed to stay, but it is *not* implied that they did this in a hurry.